# How to make Spring Hibernate Application enterprise ready?

Tags: spring, hibernate, deployment

So, I have my application based on spring and hibernate. The user produces some data (in my case the data is kind of development itself) which is persisted by hibernate.

But for now this won't be accepted by large enterprises. They want to have a development enviroment, a test environment and a production. What I need to implement is a way to deploy data from one environment to another.

To be clear: I am not asking about deploying the application, but its data.

Are there best practices to implement this feature?

Answer (score 0):

To maintain DDL and use same across various environments use liquibase or flyaway which also integrates with seamlessly with spring.

If you want DML to be migrated then vendor specific data migration can be used.

I think you are mostly looking at DDL only so either of above is better solution